# nodejs delete variable from session

Tags: node.js, variables, session

Good morning,

I'm going crazy since yesterday. I'm working on a short process to pass some messages between 2 pages. For exemple : 
- User click on a link to active his profile and go on the page ..../profile/active/?t=xxqqsqcqcq
- if the token has not been found on the database :

```
req.session.redirMessage = {'type': 'error', 'title': 'Activation profil','messages': ['Le lien que vous avez suivi n\'est pas valide.' + new Date()]};
res.redirect('/');next();
```

On the controller of the index page :

```
res.render('inc_index.jade', r);
req.session.redirMessage={};
```

If i'm checking the session values just after "req.session.redirMessage={}", it's ok redirMessage has been reinitialized. 
But if i'm refresh the index page (and not the profil activation page), the variable "req.session.redirMessage" is not empty, the value is back, it's always "{'type': 'error', 'title': 'Activation profil','messages':............."

I can add a new variable on the session (tested with req.session.idUser), but I don't found how remove a variable from the session.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

K ... I found ;(

```
req.session.save()
```

New variables are automatically added but to update it's needed to call the save process.

Have a nice day.